# A graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, computer-science, np-complete

Consider the following graph problem. For a number $K$ and a set $\mathcal{K} = \{ 1, \ldots,K\}$, we have a set of vertices $V_k^s$ for all $s \subset \mathcal{K} \setminus \{k\}$, $s$ is not empty and for all $k$. For example, if $K =2$, we have $V_1^{\{2\}}$ and $V_2^{\{1\}}$. if $K =3$, we have $V_1^{\{2,3\}}$, $V_1^{\{2\}}$, $V_1^{\{3\}}$, $V_2^{\{1,3\}}, V_2^{\{1\}}, V_2^{\{3\}}, V_3^{\{1,2\}}, V_3^{\{1\}}, V_3^{\{2\}}$. 
The weight of vertex $V_k^s$ is denoted by $v_k^s$.

There is an edge between two vertices $V_k^s$ and $V_l^t$, if $k \in t$ and $l \in s$. For example, for $K=3$, there is an edge between $V_1^{\{2,3\}}$ and $V_2^{\{1\}}$, but there is no edge between $V_1^{\{2\}}$ and $V_3^{\{1\}}$.

The resulting graphs for $K=2$ and $K=3$ have been shown in the two following figures. Note that the corresponding graph for $K=k$ have $Q_k = k \times (2^{k-1}-1)$ vertices.
[image]
[image]

For each clique (complete subgraph) of the original graph, the weight is defined as the maximum of the weights of the vertices of the clique. More specifically, if vertices $X_1, \ldots, X_k$ form a clique where $x_i$ is the weight of vertex $X_i$, then the weight of this clique is $\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_k \}$.

For a given number $K$ and its corresponding graph, we want to find the minimum weight subgraph consisting of disjoint cliques which includes all vertices (that is, all vertices are present in the subgraph and each vertex is exactly in one clique). I want to know whether this problem is NP-complete? I am looking for an algorithm (probably approximation) which runs in polynomial time of $Q_K$.

---

**A more general problem**: Consider the following graph problem. For a number $K$, a set $\mathcal{K} = \{ 1, \ldots,K\}$, and $b_1, \ldots, b_K$, we have a set of vertices $V_{k,b_k}^s$ for all $s \subset \mathcal{K} \setminus \{k\}$, $s$ is not empty and for all $k$. The weight of vertex $V_{k,b_k}^s$ is denoted by $v_{k,b_k}^s$ and $v_{k,b_k}^s = v_{l,b_l}^s$ if $b_k = b_l$.

1) There is an edge between two vertices $V_{k,b_k}^s$ and $V_{l,b_l}^t$, if $k \in t$ and $l \in s$. 2) There is an edge between two vertices $V_{k,b_k}^s$ and $V_{l,b_l}^s$, if $b_k = b_l$.

If all $b_1, \ldots, b_K$ are different, then this problem becomes the one described above.

Comment: We need to find a subgraph of the initially given graph, which includes all the vertices and has minimum sum weight, right?

Comment: @Stefan4024 exactly.

Comment: @Stefan4024 Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not really. At first I thought of using the Greedy Algorithm by starting at connected vertex with highest value and then connect it to the vertex with highest value that is connected to it. But unfortunately I found some counter-example.

Comment: @Stefan4024 I added an approach to the question. It can be modeled as an integer programming. Do you think it is correct?

Comment: You can model this as a integer knapsack problem. Enumerate all possible subgraphs. Treat each subgraph $S$ as an "item" for the knapsack problem, whose weight is $\sum_{j \in S} 2^j$ and whose value is $\max_{j \in S} G_j$. Then you just need to find a set of "item"s whose weight sums to exactly $2^{10}-1$ and whose value is minimal.

Comment: @Irvan That was a nice observation. Thanks. Then we can use dynamic programming to solve it.

Comment: This feels like an np problem.

Comment: @gowrath Yes, I had the same feeling and that's why I was looking for a known NP problem that can be reduced to this problem. But I just came up with the suggested Greedy algorithm and I check it for different values of the weights of the vertices and it gave the optimal solution.

Comment: @m0_as Nicely done. Did you use the knapsack problem?

Comment: @gowrath You mean using knapsack problem and trying to reduce it to this problem?

Comment: @m0_as Indeed :)

Comment: @gowrath No, I actually couldn't show that. I mean I couldn't find any NP problem that can be reduced to this problem.

Comment: Is your graph has only $9$ vertices? Or that was only an example?

Comment: @Azzo This in only an example. But I thought solving this is a good step for solving the main problem.

Comment: @Irvan Your suggested algorithm works but it's complexity is high. Do you know any algorithm for solving this problem that runs in polynomial order of $Q_K$?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1833883/14578, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68405/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how these graphs are chordal.  Suppose $K \geq 4$.  Consider the vertices $V_1^{2}, V_2^{1,3}, V_2^{1,3,4}, V_3^{2}$.  Wouldn't these vertices induce a $C_4$?

Comment: @ManuelLafond No, they don't. there is no edge between the second and third vertices because $2 \not \in \{1,3,4\}$ and again $2 \not \in \{1,3\}$. Even, there is no edge between the fourth and first one. Maybe I didn't get your cycle correctly.

Comment: @ManuelLafond But you are right, my graphs are not chordal :( this is an example: $V_1^2,V_2^{1,3}, V_1^{2,3,4},V_2^{1,4}$.

Comment: @ManuelLafond Thanks for your comment. It was really helpful. My graphs might still be perfect by some other property, I hope so. Otherwise, we cannot say it is solvable nor it is NP-complete.

Comment: "the cliques." ​ -> ​ "the maximal cliques." ​ ​ ​ ? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ Otherwise, each vertex weight should itself be a summand, rather than some of them just being in a $\max$. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Sorry, I didn't get your comment. Can you explain more?

Comment: $\left\{\hspace{-0.04 in}V_1^{\{2\}}\hspace{-0.04 in}\right\}$ is a clique in the graph just above "For a given", but $v_1^{\{2\}}$ is not a summand of the sum you wrote just above that diagram. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer If you mean the last figure, there $V_1^{\{2\}}$ is connected to $V_2^{\{1\}}$ and they together form a clique for that particular subgraph. So, the weight of that clique is max $\{v_1^{\{2\}}, v_2^{\{1\}} \}$. If we have another subgraph where $V_1^{\{2\}}$ and $V_2^{\{1\}}$ are not connected (and not connected to any other vertices), then instead of max $\{v_1^{\{2\}}, v_2^{\{1\}} \}$, we have $v_1^{\{2\}} +v_2^{\{1\}}$. The problem is exactly this that for each vertex, among all possible cliques to which it belongs, which of them should be selected. Did you get what I meant?

Comment: "they together form a clique for that particular subgraph", but $V_1^{\{2\}}$ on its own _also_ forms "a clique for that particular subgraph", and $v_1^{\{2\}}$ on its own is not a summand of the sum you wrote $\big(\hspace{-0.03 in}$even though ​ $\max \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(\hspace{-0.04 in}v_1^{\{2\}}\hspace{-0.03 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}v_2^{\{1\}}\hspace{-0.03 in}\right)$ ​ is$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)$. ​ ​ ​ Yes, and the expressions you're writing seem to corresponding to just selecting the _maximal_ cliques, rather than _all_ of them. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I didn't mean that we cannot decompose that subgraph (of last figure) to smaller cliques. This is just a possible solution to the problem. What you are talking about (exactly the same subgraph but no connection between $V_1^{\{2\}}$ and $V_2^{\{1\}}$) is another possible solution with a different weight (what you said). Even the subgraph where all vertices are disjoint (none of them connected to any other) is also a possible solution with a different weight. We exactly want to find the one with the lowest weight. So, no we don't want to select necessarily maximal cliques.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53437/discussion-between-ricky-demer-and-m0-as).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all weights are with a factor W of each other, then you can get a

W-approximation by just pretending they're all equal and applying

the linear-time solution mentioned in your question's last paragraph.

One can get an efficient ​ $\ln(Q_k)$-approximation ​ by

using [Algorithm 3.1.7](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/880-S07/scribe-notes/lecture03.pdf#page=3) and finding the $\operatorname{argmax}$s as follows:

Vertices in the same column are not adjacent, so cliques have at most one vertex in each column. ​ ​ ​ Brute-force over the possibilities for which set P of not-already-covered columns the

non-empty clique uses. ​ ​ ​ (There are at only 2$^k$-1 possibilities, and if ​ 1 < k ​ then ​ 2$^k$-1 < Q<sub>k</sub> .)

For each column in P, find the minimum weight of not-already-covered vertices

whose superscripts each include the indices of the other columns in P.

If any elements of P have no such vertices then P does not induce any cliques,

else with M being the maximum of those minimum weights,

[M is the weight of the minimum-weight cliques that induce P] and

[those cliques are formed by choosing, for each column in P, exactly one of the vertices in that column which is such that [the vertex's superscript includes the indices of all *other* columns in P] and [the vertex's weight is at most M]].

By "subgraph" in the rest of this answer, I mean [induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph).

Pretending the not-in-the-subgraph vertices are already covered turns that into

a poly$(Q_k)$-time ln(n)-approximation for n-vertex subgraphs of your graphs.

Observe that solutions always restrict to no-more-expensive solutions to subgraphs, so in particular the minimum cost for a subgraph cannot exceed the minimum cost for the original graph.

Thus, what I described two sentences ago can be used as a heuristic to hopefully get better

lower bounds, and as a special case of that, yields an algorithm which provably achieves better approximation bounds when most weights are much smaller than the maximum weight:

Split the graph into a large low-weight part and a small (n-vertex) high-weight part.

Combining a cover of the low-weight part with a ln(n)-approximation for

the high-weight part yields a cover of the input graph whose cost is at most

[cost for low-weight part] ​ ​ ​ + ​ ​ ​ [ ln(n) ​ $\cdot$ ​ [optimum cost for input graph] ] ​ .

If n is sufficiently small, then you can do even better by using an

[Exponential-Time Approximation of Weighted Set Cover](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~kowalik/papers/setcover.pdf) on the high-weight part.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested approach. Can you explain more simply about your third paragraph? I didn't get it. One more question, do you think this problem is NP-hard?

Comment: What are you counting as "paragraph"s? ​ (i.e., what does my "third paragraph" start and end with?) ​ I suppose I'd guess that this problem _is_ NP-hard. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The paragraph that starts with "Vertices in the same column are not adjacent, so cliques have at most one vertex in each column." Do you have any idea for showing that this is NP-hard?

Comment: Are you wondering about _how to perform_ or just _correctness of_ the procedure? ​ My vague idea is two possible weights, one much larger than the other, so that graph-coloring on the complement of the large-weight subgraph reduces to your problem. ​ (I can explain how _that_ reduction works if you'd like, but I have no idea regarding showing hardness of those graph-coloring problems.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I actually cannot understand the meaning of that paragraph. For example, what do these sentence mean? "Brute-force over the possibilities for which set S of not-already-covered columns the 
non-empty clique uses.", "For each column in S, find the minimum-weight not-already-covered vertices 
whose superscripts each include the indices of the other columns in S." Since I cannot understand these two, I cannot get the rest of that paragraph as well.

Comment: Regarding NP-hardness proof, you are saying that your idea is to reduce graph-coloring on a specific class of graphs to the graphs of my problem? I am not sure how this can help, because then we are facing with a graph-coloring problem on a specific class of graphs which is not clear that it is NP-hard. This is somehow similar to the original problem, we have weighted set cover problem on a special class of graph and we cannot claim about NP-hardness using NP-hardness of set cover problem for general graphs.

Comment: For any given column, do you know how you'd find which vertices in that column are in at least one of the already-chosen cliques? ​ Do you know how you would find which columns are such that for each of their vertices, that vertex is in at least one of the already-chosen cliques? ​ Do you know how to write a program that takes k as input and outputs all subsets of {1,2,3,...,k-2,k-1,k}? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes, since I'm aware of hardness results for fairly-restricted graph-classes but not not to the point of at-most-one-graph-per-number-of-verteices, even when weights are allowed. ​ ​

Comment: I didn't mean I don't know how to implement them. Can you rephrase that paragraph? I meant I can't get it, maybe I am not good at reading! I know the answer to the three questions you asked, but I think your explanation in the third paragraph is somehow concise. I appreciate if you rephrase it.

Comment: So, you find the set of columns which have at least one vertex such that [the vertex is in _none_ of the already-chosen cliques]. ​ The next part o the code would be like outputting all subsets of that set of columns, but instead of just outputting those columns, it will be skipping the empty set and doing stuff (namely "find the minimum-weight ... columns in S.") to the other subsets of that set of columns. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Still didn't get. You are saying Brute force ..., but brute force to do what? what we are looking for at that step for which you are suggesting brute force? What is your definition of $S$? It seems it includes 1 to $k$ at first, but if all vertices of column $i$ have been already covered, we remove $i$ from $S$. Is that right? Then, you are saying "For each column in S, find the minimum-weight not-already-covered vertices 
whose superscripts each include the indices of the other columns in S.", but for each column, we can have one vertex in a clique, so what does finding ... vertices mean?

Comment: I guess by "For each column in S, find the minimum-weight not-already-covered vertices 
whose superscripts each include the indices of the other columns in S.", you mean if $S =\{1,2,3\}$, find $T_1,T_2,T_3$ such that weights of $V_1^{T_1}, V_2^{T_2}, V_3^{T_3}$ are minimum. You mean for each column choose the vertex with the lowest weight or the whole cost of the resulting clique should be minimized? If you write an algorithm instead of these explanation, it would be more clear.

Comment: In the past, I came up with an approximation algorithm. I had deleted that as a solution because there was a counter-example for optimality (On that point, I thought it is optimal). Do you know how we can find a optimality bound for such an approximation?

Comment: Sorry, one more question, in cover set problem, we are looking for approximation which are polynomial in n and m (n number of elements, m number of sets), right? So, your suggested approach has the complexity polynomial in $Q_k$ and number of all possible cliques, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53577/discussion-between-ricky-demer-and-m0-as).

Comment: Do you know any formal (like a book) reference that has approximation algorithms like Algorithm 3.17 for set cover problem?

Comment: No. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: One question, we know that if cliques $Q_1, ... Q_N$ are optimal for this problem, we can find disjoint cliques $L_1,...,L_M$ with same cost. So, we can restrict attention to disjoint cliques because we know there is an optimal solution there. So, in Algorithm 3.17, when we choose set $s$, not only we can remove $s$ from $\mathcal{S}$, but also we can remove any other set $S \in \mathcal{S}$ whose intersection with $s$ is not empty, right? If we do so, then in the next iteration, maximizing over $\mathcal{S}$ is the same the algorithm you suggested.

Comment: I meant otherwise, if we choose columns 1 and 2 for example, the numerator of argmax expression is not the same for all possible cliques. Assume P={1,2}, then all "C-cliques" are [{2,3},{1,3}], [{2,3},{1}],[{2},{1,3}], [{2},{1}]. But if we have already chosen V_2^{1} somehow, then for [{2,3},{1,3}], [{2},{1,3}], the numerator is 2 but for [{2,3},{1}],[{2},{1}], it is 1.

Comment: "So, in ... not empty, right?" ​ Yes. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: This is an extra question: if we have the following condition, can we still use your approach (possibly modified version)? Assume v_1^3 = v_2^3. Conditions: if we choose clique of V_1^3 and V_3^{1,2}, we don't need to select V_2^3 anymore. In other words, for Q = [V_1^3,V_3^{1,2}], $|Q \cap E| = 3$ and not two. Similarly, if we choose clique of V_2^3 and V_3^{1,2}, we don't need to select V_1^3 anymore. If we choose clique of V_1^3 (or clique of V_2^3), we don't need to choose V_2^3 (or V_1^3). But if we choose the clique of V_1^3 and V_3^1, we still have to select V_2^3 later.

Comment: We can address this condition by adding an edge between V_1^3 and V_2^3. Then, since they have the same size, if algorithm wants to choose either, it is better to choose both  1/x < 2/x. Similarly, then V_1^3, V_2^3, V_3^{1,2} becomes a clique which is better than [V_1^3,V_3^{1,2}] or [V_2^3,V_3^{1,2}]. So adding that edges solve the issue if we don't care about the complexity. But, if we add that edge, then we cannot have the decomposition you suggested

Comment: Well, for that, you can just brute-force over whether-or-not that clique is chosen. ​ If you have _more_ such constraints, then their form will be important. ​ (One might be able to perform a $\big[$brute-force over the set of possibilities for $|Q\cap E|\big]$ for set-of-columns separately.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation to the end of my question (A more general problem).

Comment: Do you have any idea for the general problem? We can ignore those new edges and follow your algorithm, but I don't know whether than $Ln(Q_k)$-approximation holds or not.

Comment: Your 2) just creates some [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)), which suggests that you intended something different. ​ In the context of loops, cliques can't have vertices without loops, so if your $b$s are not all different, then your new graphs will have no clique covers. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Why only loops and no cliques? For example if $b_1 = b_2$, then we add an edge to the graph of second figure between $V_{b_1}^{\{3\}}$ and $V_{b_2}^{\{3\}}$. Adding these, create two new cliques, $[V_{b_1}^{\{3\}}, V_{b_2}^{\{3\}}, V_{b_3}^{\{1,2\}}]$ and $[V_{b_1}^{\{3\}}, V_{b_2}^{\{3\}}]$. It also creates some loops but we are not looking for loops, so we don't care about them. We still want to find clique cover with minimum weight. But compared to the previous problem, we have two more cliques now.

Comment: Maybe what you are saying is because you consider those two vertices $V_{b_1}^{\{3\}}$ and $V_{b_2}^{\{3\}}$ the same when $b_1 = b_2$. We want to treat them as two different vertices as want to cover both of them.

Comment: So, did you intend to have things like $V^{\{3\}}_{1,b_1}$ and $V^{\{3\}}_{2,b_2}$ rather than $V^{\{3\}}_{b_1}$ and $V^{\{3\}}_{b_2}$? ​ ​

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, my notation is confusing. Yes, I meant exactly what you said.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to instead restrict to vertices whose superscripts include the columns-in-P whose $b$s are different from the vertex's $b$. ​ (One will recover that those are exactly the ways to choose cliques-in-the-new-graph whose projection is P.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I am not sure if I get what you said. Can you please explain more? We already had "Brute-force over the possibilities for which set P of not-already-covered columns the 
non-empty clique uses. For each column in P, find the minimum weight of not-already-covered vertices whose superscripts each include the indices of the other columns in S."

Comment: What I got form what you said is this:  "Brute-force over the possibilities for which set P of not-already-covered columns the non-empty clique uses, the column which have different b . For each column in P, find the minimum weight of not-already-covered vertices 
whose superscripts each include the indices of the other columns in S. "

Comment: But I don't think that's what you are saying. because in this case, the new clique will never be chosen.

Comment: That S was something I had forgotten to change to P. ​ Your new problem does not change which Ps you should try - It changes which vertices from each column in P can be in cliques whose projections are P. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54951/discussion-between-m0-as-and-ricky-demer).

Comment: (I finally commented in the chat again.) ​ ​

Comment: Can you please read this comment: I just checked the above algorithm for this case: {'V_1^[3]': 10, 'V_1^[2]': 1, 'V_1^[2, 3]': 7, 'V_2^[3]': 10, 'V_2^[1]': 10, 'V_2^[1, 3]': 8, 'V_3^[1]': 5, 'V_3^[2]': 7, 'V_3^[1, 2]': 3}, and the linear algorithm works much better for that. Do you have any idea for modifying the above algorithm?

Comment: What is ​ "the linear algorithm" ? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: this one: $\{V_1^{\{2,3\}}, V_2^{\{1,3\}}, V_3^{\{1,2\}}\}$, $\{V_1^{\{2\}}, V_2^{\{1\}}\}$, $\{V_1^{\{3\}}, V_3^{\{1\}}\}$, $\{V_2^{\{3\}}, V_3^{\{2\}}\}$

Comment: If we apply the algorithm you suggested, the output is: $\{V_1^{2}\},\{V_1^{2, 3}, V_2^{1, 3}, V_3^{1, 2}\},  \{V_3^{1}\}, \{V_2^{3}, V_3^{2}\}, \{V_1^{3}\}, \{V_2^{1}\}$. One quick observation is that, two cliques $\{V_1^{2}\}$ and $\{V_2^{1}\}$ can be combined to one clique to reduce the sum weight. Similarly, two cliques $\{V_1^{3}\}$ and $\{V_3^{1}\}$.

Comment: If we apply the algorithm you suggested, the output is: $\{V_1^{2}\}$. If we look at the first clique which is the output of your algorithm, it is $\{V_1^{2}\}$. But, we know that the worst one can do is to cover a vertex by choosing a clique including only that vertex. One way to improve this algorithm is maybe to do this: if the algorithm outputs a clique, check whether we can add more vertices to this clique and still be a clique. I meant, we say okay choose $\{V_1^{2}\}$ but either of $\{V_2^{1}\}$ or $\{V_2^{1,3}\}$ can be added to that as well. But this increases the runtime of algorithm

Comment: I think the main reason this happens is that we haven't used the fact that if a clique includes a set of vertices, then the size of that clique is the maximum of size of the vertices and not the sum of them. It was sum of them, then it wasn't important to have to cliques of \{V_1^2\} and \{V_2^1\} or one clique of \{V_1^2,V_2^1\}. Do you think there is anyway to use this property in your algorithm?

Comment: Am I right about the output of your proposed algorithm?

Comment: Is ​ "the proposed algorithm" ​ the algorithm I described or ​ "the linear algorithm" ? ​ ​ ​ If that latter, than what is that algorithm? ​ ​ ​ (The comment 5 before this one just gives a partition into cliques, rather than an algorithm.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I am sorry if my comments weren't clear. by "proposed algorithm" I meant the one you described. I updated the question and described what I meant by "linear algorithm". I thought you know what it is based on the first paragraph of your response that you refer to that.

Comment: Isn't the approximation ration for the weighted set cover log(n) +1 (instead of log(n)) for a problem with n elements? I found it here http://www.cse.nd.edu/~izaguirr/papers/simon/ChenBang%20-%20proteinNetwork/literatures/SetCovering/Johnson.pdf  where I think is the first paper found this result. Or in this paper: A Greedy Heuristic for the Set-Covering Problem by V. Chvatal. The ration is $(1+ 1/2 + ... + 1/n)$ which is between $log(n)$ and $log(n)+1$.